# How do I avoid Gimbal Lock when using Mathf.Clamp?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code works perfectly to achieve the results I want, but when I enter and exit the trigger my rotation snaps to 35 degrees in World/Global forward.

I know that I am using `eulerAngles` for both the x and y axis but it's the only way I know how to achieve clamping on both axis.

I have the exact same code minus the lines with `yRotation` that I use for general movement. The snippet below is only used while inside a trigger. I have made sure there is no code overlapping with one another and the "snap" is still present.

```cs
// attached to camera and is inside Update() once OnTriggerEnter activates

float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;

xRotation -= mouseY;
yRotation += mouseX;

xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
yRotation = Mathf.Clamp(yRotation, -35f, 35f);

transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
player.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, yRotation, 0f); // rotate player object
```

When I replace `transform.eulerAngles` with `Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0f)`, the clamping result that I want is gone.

Comment: Could you clarify what this script is attached to and how it stands in relation to the `player` object? It's also not quite clear what you want changed with your code. Should it ease in instead of snapping or use some local reference rotation?

Comment: So right now when I enter the relevant trigger, my camera snaps forward, in direction of the world which should not happen. When I enter the trigger, my camera should not move unless I am manually moving it. The camera script is attached to my camera. So what I am trying to change is getting rid of that camera snap/gimbal lock. The player.transform.eulerangles line is just to rotate my player itself

Comment: So should the clamp apply relative to the view direction that you enter into the trigger?

Comment: It is still a bit confusing ... you say `my camera snaps forward` and `my camera should not move` ... nothing in your code "moves" the camera, only rotates it .. so what exactly is the desired behavior vs what exactly is happening instead? Maybe some graphics would help to understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

Setting rotations to vectors can be tricky. Try using the Quaternion.Euler:

```
player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, yRotation, 0f);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work no matter how I try to implement it. The gimbal lock is still in effect and my camera on the y axis snaps 30 degrees forward.